# AS3 API for generating Form from Model

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I did a quick search through the net looking for it before start making it myself. I'd like to write a model class, add some annotations to it and generate a form and/or set it as attribute of a certain component which will build a form for CRUD operations. I found none source-code nor .swc built to use and try. Does anyone knows where I can find AS3 APIs like this one and maybe others API that could be useful for Enterpirse Softwares made in Flex/AS3? Thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something in these links : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/Form.html http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e53.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62f1b-7fdb and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e973827a8e912ac2b325a4-8000.html

Comment: @abhinav As I understand it, the OP wants to automatically generate these Forms from the model classes instead of manually writing them. I know only of the Flex add-on for [Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) that does this, but it's fairly dated and I didn't like the results very much. As for other API's for enterprise projects: there are hundreds, you'll have to be more specififc to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: @RIAstar Where to find such things? It seems to me that AS3 community is completely dead and the common forums which discuss as3 doesn't have much of well-written API to automatize development. Most of them are API with start but without end. Until now, I still suffer sometimes to deal with masked Input text as in Phone Numbers and etc; because the components available on the internet aren't much of a success to deal with it.

Comment: A lot of new stuff is being added to the Apache Flex project as we speak, and I can assure you from the traffic on the mailing list that the project is far from dead. I am still unclear as to what you mean by `well-written API to automatize development`. As for a masked TextInput component: I've written one myself, but it's not sufficiently robust for publication.

Comment: By that I meant projects that doesn't stop on the first version. I've already tried three different masked TextInput component, which the first one didn't accept paste into it and could not be fixed as the engineering model that it assumed to mask the component couldn't handle more than 1 character at a time.
The one I'm using now cannot be linked to any bindable attribute in flex as if you clean up the attribute, the field will not be cleaned.

Comment: But TextInput is a small problem and I'm not crying about it. I'd like APIs for bigger things as automatize Forms/CRUDs, but not generating a lot of codes that will require a lot of maintenance, That's why I was thinking about some component that receives a given Model as Object, runs through it and creates the form from AS3 dynamically, which could be a front-door to a component which would automatize my whole CRUD.